# Further Explanation needed: Initial value of reference to non-const must be a lvalue

Tags: c++, user-interface, graphics, lvalue

Project scope: Academic

Intended purpose: Have a GUI for project submission. This question involves making a defined area of the graphics window *clickable.* I'm not familiar with other graphic libraries.

I have looked elsewhere on this site and read similar postings about this error: "initial value of reference to a non-const must be lvalue." I really need some further explanations to solving this:

```
    #include "graph1.h"`
 displayPNG("solve.png", 560, 120);
int x2 = 560 + 54; 
  int x1 = 560;
  int y1 = 120;
  int y2 = 291 + 120;
  const int * xSolv2 = &x2;
  const int * xSolv1 = &x1;
  displayPNG("exit.png",545,415);

  //Game (loop) play for buttons, options & clickables. 
  //while (true){
   if (leftMouse((xSolv2 > xSolv1) && (x1 < &x2), (&y2 > &y1) && (&y1 < &y2)))  //error: "Initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue."
   {
      cout << "Test button functions properly" << endl;
   }
```

I have attempted the following variations but with no success.

```
//shortened for brevity purposes. 
bool function (&x,&y) 
bool function (*x,*y) // I had created some pointer var(s) earlier and initialized them.
```

`bool function(x, y)`

If anyone has experience using "graph1.h" with graphicLib2015.lib I am eager to learn.

Comment: `x1 < &x2` why are you comparing a value to an address?

Comment: `(&y2 > &y1) && (&y1 < &y2)` This is also a very verbose way of saying `(&y1 < &y2)`

Comment: Minor suggestion: the code will be easier to change if you define `x2 = x1 + 54;` for example.

Comment: The feeling when googling "graphicLib2015" returns me right back to this same StackOverflow question

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but you can eliminate `xSolv1` and `xSolv2`. If you need a pointer to `x1`, you can provide `&x1` instead.

Pointers are a great source of !!fun!! and unexpected behaviour. When you say `(xSolv2 > xSolv1)` - you're comparing the memory locations of `x1` and `x2`! That's almost certainly not what you wanted ☺

As you said the signature is `bool leftMouse(int &x, int &y)`, you probably want to do something like…

```
int x;
int y;
leftMouse(x, y); // probably will update x and y with the mouse position
if (x1 < x && x < x2 && y1 < y && y < y2 ) {
  // then the mouse is in box
}
```

Comment: Actually all the `(&foo < &bar)` comparisons are a little odd - again they're comparing memory address locations. What arguments does `leftMouse` take??

Comment: bool leftMouse(int &x, int &y)

Comment: OK, so I guess you give it two `int`s and it updates them. Then you check if they're in your defined region.

Comment: I had deference them once and it still did not take.

Comment: I've updated my answer (again) - if an function takes a reference as an argument, you don't need to dereference it.